# computer goes back to sleep after a few seconds without any error message

Tags: 19.10, hibernate, debug

I encounter a problem with my ubuntu 19.10 with gnome install on a laptop(razor blade from 2017). As quite unexperienced with the linux architecture, I failed fixing it by myself; the main reason being the lack of error message. I'm using the nvidia driver as ubuntu fails to log me in when using X.org (even in text mode for some reason).

From boot, everything works fine. The computer can go to sleep from the lid being closed, CTRL+L and automatic sleep from inaction seemingly fine. The computer will also go out of sleep seemingly fine by keyboard press and continue to work fine for a few second, around a minute, but then will go back to sleep unprompted. I may make it go back from sleep again but the same effect will occur again.

I've tried the adding `nomodeset` and `nouveau.modeset=0` (not a the same time) in the grub. I've tried a clean install but the problem persits.

That must be easy problem to fix but I'm clueless on how to figure out what is failing. Could you kindly help me ?

Thank you very much, Nathan.